# Dereference symlinks from a path

Tags: bash, symlink

I have path to a file `/home/jcubic/www/shell/config.json` where www is symlink to `/domains/jcubic.pl/public_html` is it posible to get path `/home/jcubic/domains/jcubic.pl/public_html/shell/config.json` from `/home/jcubic/www/shell/config.json`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `realpath` or `readlink` command to follow symbolic links:

```
realpath /home/jcubic/www/shell/config.json
readlink -f /home/jcubic/www/shell/config.json
```

or use `-m` if the links may be broken but you still want the result.